# pooled, fixed or random effects

Tags: regression, panel-data

I have a panel dataset similar to the one generated with:

```
mydata <- data.frame(individual = rep(letters[1:5], each = 5),
                     year = rep(2001:2005, 5),
                     y = rnorm(25, 10, 2),
                     x1 = rnorm(25, 30, 5),
                     x2 = rnorm(25, 50, 10))
```

The dataset looks like:

```
  individual  year         y       x1       x2
      (fctr) (int)     (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1          a  2001  8.910741 29.79987 50.40676
2          a  2002 10.720026 29.85172 59.84674
3          a  2003 12.006213 23.95960 55.64508
4          a  2004  8.035900 37.32669 45.31313
5          a  2005 14.080549 35.39554 33.70688
6          b  2001 10.006366 28.32613 24.66884
... ...
... ...
```

The dataset I am working with is a collection of economic indicator variables, *e.g., GDP growth, stock market capitalization, interest rate*, over the period 2001-2010.

The question I want to address is *to what extent do changes in `x1`, `x2` or interaction thereof cause change in `y`*?

Which of the regression models - pooled, fixed effects or random effects - should be used here? According to [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf) (page 2), it seems pooled model should be used in this case. Am I right assuming so?

Comment: It depends on what your research question is.  What *is* your research question?

Comment: That's not very helpful.  What are your hypotheses?  Were you thinking about analysing the data as panel?  Why do you think you need to do a panel?  The method you choose depends on the hypothesis you're trying to test (this is generally true, by the way).  Please edit your question to include more details about your research, since we're not mind-readers and we don't know ultimately what you're trying to answer, so it's hard to comment on whether pooled is truly superior to fixed or random effects in your context.

Comment: Before plumping for just one, you may find [Bell and Jones, 2014](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233756428_Explaining_Fixed_Effects_Random_Effects_Modeling_of_Time-Series_Cross-Sectional_and_Panel_Data) worth reading.

Comment: You might also work through `lme4`'s [sleep study](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/sleepstudy) example.  It looks rather similar to your problem as you describe it.

Comment: Bell and Jones article seems helpful. Thanks! @conjugateprior